# react-native-background-timer inconsistently works on Android for recording audio

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6, react-native

I am using `BackgroundTimer` from `react-native-background-timer` in a React native project for Android.

I want a user to be able to record audio after a set duration (e.g. record for 5 minutes after 30 minutes).

The issue I have is that it works "sometimes". It seems the OS is often killing the process - especially if the time to execute is longer.

Code extract:

```
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';
...

// Start a timer that runs once after X milliseconds
const timeout1 = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {

    // Should work when when app is the the background
    this.onStartRecord();

    const timeout2 = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
        this.onStopRecord();
        BackgroundTimer.clearTimeout(timeout2);
    }, millisRecording);

    // Clear first timeout
    BackgroundTimer.clearTimeout(timeout1);

}, millisUntilRecordMoment);
```

Thes rest of the code is here: https://github.com/bentaly/listen/blob/master/App.tsx

I have also tried building this in Expo previously which didn't work.

Is there anyway to guarantee this operation will work?

Answer (score 0):

You will have around ~40 seconds to call your function and call the completion handler in the background state or phone is in the sleep state.

If you don't finish it on time, iOS will kill your app. If you don't obey the rules, iOS will give you less chances to wake up. For more detailed usage of Background Modes, you may check following tutorial

It is due to app developers abusing this mechanism, killing their customers' device battery.

**Note:** Watchdog Timeout is ~40 sec.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, did you mean to link an article? Also this question specifically asked about Android

Comment: "It seems the OS is often killing the process - especially if the time to execute is longer." it seems of ios question

Comment: OS stands for operating system, such as iOS, Android, Windows, Linux etc

Comment: sorry i suppose to be IOS. i will let you know after some search

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, it was a good answer for IOS! Hopefully will help someone in the future

Comment: @BenTaliadoros are you using huawei android phone? because my friend facing same issue on android huawei device not other and he put silent 1 second secound to hack os kill process

Comment: I havent, I guess being different models you will get issues. What is the 1 second hack?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros there was the same issue on ios, he played silent 1-second audio every 8 seconds to prevent killing the process. but he said I got this issue on android only Huawei devices

Comment: I will but I won't be able for a few days, if it works I'll let you know and you can update as a separate answer